# Set image for Imagebutton in Xamarin for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

I'm trying to customize an imagebutton to use specific images on particular devices for android is will show one image while in iOS it will show an other image using custom renderers

I have finished on the Android side but noticed that iOS uses different memeber variables instead of just "this.SetBackground(Some Resource)" used on the android side.

```
namespace FlipXamarin.Controls
{
    public class FingerPrintLabel : ImageButton
    {
        public FingerPrintLabel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

```
Android
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FingerPrintLabel), typeof(FingerPrintLabelRenderer))]
namespace FlipXamarin.Droid.Renderers
{

    public class FingerPrintLabelRenderer : ImageButtonRenderer
    {

        public FingerPrintLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context) 
        {

        }


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ImageButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            this.SetBackground(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.fingerprint_2x));
        }
    }
}
```

```
iOS
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FingerPrintLabel), typeof(FingerPrintLabelRenderer))]
namespace FlipXamarin.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class FingerPrintLabelRenderer : ImageButtonRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ImageButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            ///if(iOS.version == 8) show fingerprint icon
            ///if(iOS.version == 10 and) show FaceId icon
        }
    }
}
```

Android should just show a Fingerprint icon while iOS will show a fingerprint or faceId icon.

[Android Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRfeN.png)

Comment: Is it really necessary to use a custom renderer?  The Device helper class will let your determine platform and version at runtime, so you can just set the appropriate image from within your shared Forms code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jason has indicated in the comments, you don't need a custom renderer to show a different image since you can do all this from the Shared Project using the `Device` helper class.

But, to answer your question, if you want to update the Image of the `ImageButton` from a `CustomRenderer` in iOS you can do it like this:

```
//Do your validation as you wish, this was just an example.
var image = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0)
                ? UIImage.FromBundle("facescan.jpg")
                : UIImage.FromBundle("fingerprint.jpg");

//The Control property is an UIButtton
Control?.SetImage(image?.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), UIControlState.Normal);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms , you can install [Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo) to determine which version number .

**Xaml** as follow :

```
<ImageButton x:Name="MyImageButton" Source="fingerprint.png"/>
```

Then in **ContentPage** , if has intalled DeviceInfo Nuget , you can use as follow :

```
using System.ComponentModel;

if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{        
    Console.WriteLine("version is -- " + CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Version);
    if (Convert.ToInt32(CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Version) >= 10)
    {
        MyImageButton.Source = "FaceId.png";
    }
    else
    {
        MyImageButton.Source = "fingerprint.png";
    }
}
else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    MyImageButton.Source = "fingerprint.png";
}
```

If not knowing about Installing Nuget Package , you can refer to this [Install and use a package in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio).

Comment: I didnt know you can reference files from the forms project.

Comment: @AnthonyR Okey ,have a look at this .(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#displaying-images)  I think using Custom Renderer here does not make the program more concise.If you use Custom Renderer, you need to add a Renderer file to each of iOS and Android, and Forms only needs to add images to their respective platforms. Custom Renderer is used when Forms can't be implemented, so you can keep the code as simple and convenient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make use of the XAML MArkup OnPlatform.

Here is a sample:

```
  <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center">
       <ImageButton.Source>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                                        iOS="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/knowledge_graph_logo.png?201606271147"
                                        Android="https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/hAgr2LwD6AECIwsh.large" />
       </ImageButton.Source>
   </ImageButton>
```

Which results in:

[image]